# Multiple return statements?

Tags: javascript

Just scraped the following code from [a blog](https://github.com/issamalidev/bs.pagination.js/blob/master/src/bs.pagination.js) (it basically helps in converting ASP.NET `GridView`'s pagination such that bootstrap's `pagination` class could be applied to it). I'm trying to make sense of the multiple return statements in the code? Is it a typo or does Javascript actually work that way (I'm not a Javascript pro, but C++, Java and C# would skip the second `return`, C# would actually show a compile-time warning):

```
function convertToPagination(obj) {
    var list = $('<ul class="pagination"/>');

    $(obj).find("tbody tr").each(function () {
        var p = $(this).children().map(function () {
            return "<li>" + $(this).html() + "</li>";
            return $(this).html();
        });

        list.append("<li>" + $.makeArray(p).join("") + "</li>");
    });

    list.find('span').parent().addClass('active');

    $(obj).replaceWith(list);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is just buggy code. The second `return` can and will never be executed. This behaviour is equivalent for all modern [imperative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming) programming languages.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to make the following theory: the `map` function returns a Dictionary-type object and JS uses two `return` statements to let the function return its **Key** and **Value** parts. LOL.

Comment: @dotNET: that behaviour is actually possible through the use of [generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators#Generators.3A_a_better_way_to_build_Iterators) using the `yield` keyword :)   The `return` statement is however universally defined to return execution to the invoking context (ie. the caller of the current function).

Answer (score 0):

**`reutrn` used for  breaking the function,**
 so when the function is breked then there is no chances of executing next statements.

```
return "<li>" + $(this).html() + "</li>";// this will returned
return $(this).html();                   // never comes to here
```